# Restoring input/select elements from within a div after its reloaded via jquery.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have a div that contains a variable number of inputs (text, hidden) and dropdowns (each may have an ID, a name and/or one or more classes.

This div reloads from time to time and some new inputs may be added or old ones removed.

What I'm trying to do is to maintain the values entered or selected before each reload without passing current values to the server.

This here code almost does what I need except for select fields - not getting their values; once this works I can serialize that array and store it somewhere, then decode, iterate and write the values back.

```
function getAllValues() {
    var inputValues = [];
    $jq('#slip input').each(function() {
        var type = $jq(this).attr("type");
        if ((type == "checkbox" || type == "radio") && $jq(this).is(":checked")) {

            inputValues.push([ getIdentifier($jq(this)), $jq(this).val()]);
        }
        else if (type != "button" || type != "submit") {
            inputValues.push([ getIdentifier($jq(this)), $jq(this).val()]);
        }
    })
    $jq('#slip select').each(function() {
        var type = $jq(this).attr("type");
        if (type != "button" || type != "submit") {
            inputValues.push([ getIdentifier($jq(this)), $jq(this).val()]); // problem!
        }
    })
    return inputValues;
}
```

Would appreciate any input or perhaps a more elegant solution to such problem?

Later edit: Benjamin was kind enough to post a link to jquery serialize() which solved the problem very nice. In case someone else will need a bit of code to restore values saved with that:

```
function restoreSlipValues(){
    var tickets_data = decodeURIComponent($jq("#temporary-values").val()).split("&");
    console.log(tickets_data);//.split("&");
    $jq(tickets_data).each(function(){
        if (this.split("=")[0] !="authenticity_token"  && this.split("=")[0].indexOf("_win") < 0  && this.split("=")[0].indexOf("winning") < 0) {
            $jq("form#ticks input[name=\"" + this.split("=")[0] + "\"]").val(this.split("=")[1]);
            $jq("form#ticks select[name=\"" + this.split("=")[0] + "\"]").val(this.split("=")[1]);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: forms have a .serialize method http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ . Probably easiest to store in localStorage

Comment: If you want to post your message as answer to this question so I can credit you for helping out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms have a [`.serialize`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize) method. This is probably the easiest to store in localStorage in your case.

> The `.serialize()` method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It operates on a jQuery object representing a set of form elements. The form elements can be of several types.

(Glad it helped)